# Trouble Understanding Computation in Weinberg Quantum Theory of Fields Vol. 2 Chapter 22

Tags: path-integral, regularization, quantum-anomalies

In Chapter 22 (Anomalies) of Weinberg Vol. 2, the author is evaluating the anomaly function

$\mathcal{A}(x) = -2[Tr(\gamma_5 t f(-(\not{D}/M)^2))\delta(x-y)]_{y\rightarrow x}$,

following Fujikawa's regularization scheme.  To begin, Weinberg Fourier transforms the delta function, writing

$\mathcal{A}(x) = -2\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}[Tr(\gamma_5 t f(-(\not{D}/M)^2)e^{ik\cdot(x-y)}]_{x\rightarrow y} = -2\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}Tr(\gamma_5 t f(-(i\not{k} + \not{D})^2/M^2))$

My questions are the following:

(1) What does $\not{D}$ mean in the second integral?  At first, I thought it meant take $\not{D}_{\mu} = \not{\partial}_{\mu} - i\not{A}_{\mu}$ and simply replace $\not{\partial}_{\mu}$ with $i\not{k}$, but this does not seem to be correct.  This is partially because if you actually work out $\not{D}^2e^{ik\cdot(x-y)}$, you find that it has a term containing $\not{\partial}\not{A}$, which cannot be captured by the above substitution.

(2) Even if you known the answer to (1), how do you go from the first integral to the second?

(3) Weinberg provides the parenthetical statement: "A derivative with respect to $x$ gives zero when acting on the extreme right in the second expression, but not when acting on $A_{\mu}(x)$."  What does this mean? I thought maybe it meant that when the derivatives act on the exponential, they would bring down $k$'s which would cause certain terms to integrate to zero, but this doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT**
For reference, the first equation is (22.2.13).